# 400 bad request error upon getObjectMetadata request on AWS S3 after several hours of proper work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etag

*aws-java-sdk-s3 v.1.11.106*

My app app run in ECS cluster on EC2 instance.
The logic behind the app is pretty straightforward: once per 5 minutes, the cron job get launched and makes **getObjectMetadata** request in order to obtain eTag of the specific object.

Everything works fine for hours. But after several hours (the recent case was 7 hours), my app starts to get the following error again and again:
`Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 675FC4678EC190E5)`

My guess is that something gets expired (maybe some token), but I can't find what it could be.

Comment: It can be due to region change or access token. To find out root cause, better you enable logs, execute flow till it breaks  again with same error, then check logs in aws cloud of trail. You can find based on the Aws S3 event you mentioned. Later, you can disable logging if you do not want.

Comment: Hi, @amitd. Thank you for the reply.
Under 'enable logs' do you mean enable logs on EC2 instance?

Comment: I mean AWS S3 access logs . https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html